# Send slack message on Firebase Cloud Functions deployment event

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, slack-api

How can I send a slack message whenever a deployment happens on Firebase Cloud functions.
I need to send following data in message: project id, functions deployed, and deployment message if any.

I know how to send slack messages via its api but I'm not aware of any event which gets triggered on Firebase deployment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple and automatic way to accomplish the task you are looking for within Firebase. But there is a way in which you can implement it.

To do that you have to create a logging sink that matches the audit log produced when a function is deployed ([google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.functions.v1#google.cloud.functions.v1.CreateFunctionRequest)) and when a function is updated ([google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.functions.v1#google.cloud.functions.v1.UpdateFunctionRequest)). Now you can use the logging sink to trigger a Pub/Sub topic as mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/logging#functions_log_stackdriver-nodejs). Then you can create a Cloud Function which is triggered by that Pub/Sub topic as described in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub) so that the Cloud Function will be called on every new deployment. By doing this the entire log is passed into the Cloud Function which will have project id, functions deployed etc. and now within the Cloud Function you can call the Slack API to send the message.